# Sum of each row value in HashMap<String, List<RrdData>> in java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a hashmap in format of this: `HashMap<String, List<RrdData>> myData`

```
{Data1=[ [Time=1437479200, value=0.8],  [Time=1437479201, value=12]], Data2=[[Time=1437479200, value=123], [Time=1437479201, value=78]], Data3=[[fetchTime=1437479200, value=789], [Time=1437479201, value=45]}
```

I want to sum the first values for each data, then the second values and so on. For example: (the size of the array list is not static)

```
Data1.firstalue + Data2.firstValue+ Data3.firstValue.
Data1.secondValue + Data2.secondValue + Data3.secondValue
```

So in the form of vertical calculation.
What I wrote was horizontal version of it. How can I change it to vertical way?

```
for (Entry<String, List<RrdData>> counterEntry : myData.entrySet()) {
    final List<RrdData> tempValues = counterEntry.getValue();
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        sum += tempValues.getValue(i);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the longest counterEntry List. Then do

```
for (int i = 0; i<longestLength;i++){
   for (List<RrdData> counterEntry : myData.getValues()) {
       if(counterEntry.size() > i){
           sum += counterEntry.getValue(i);
      }

   }
   System.out.println(sum);
   sum = 0;
}
```

Of course this will be quite slow (since you have to loop through the whole list for each entry in it). But it's quite easy to program and understand.

If you want a faster way you could do:

```
List<Integer> sums = ArrayList<Integer>();

for (List<RrdData> counterEntry : myData.getValues()) {
   for (int i = 0; i<counterEntry.size(); i++) {
        if(sums.size > i){
            sums.get(i) += counterEntry.getValue(i);
         }else 
            sums.add(counterEntry.getValue(i);
    } 
}
```

Which saves all sums to a list.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but I am a bit lost. what is d in d.getValue(i);?

Comment: Sorry. Copied a little to much from your code. I have updated it now.

Comment: but I want the values in this form: Data1.firstalue + Data2.firstValue+ Data3.firstValue. what you provided sums all the values

Comment: The first method will print the sum and reset after each value (it will first sum all firstValues and then reset and so on). THe second method will give you a array with the first values in spot 0, and second values in spot 1 and so on.

Comment: ok thank you! I am still struggeling with that :) could you tell me what sums.get(i) += counterEntry.getValue(i); does? when I use sums.get(i)  it complains that "left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable"

Comment: I didn't actually test it, so there might be something wrong there somewhere.

sums.get(i) should return the integer in sums at location i. Which is the sum of that row (e.g. sums.get(0) would get the sum of all the first numbers). 

It might be that you need to break it up. 

Integer tempSum = Integer.valueOf(sums.get(i));
tempSum += counterEntry.getValue(i));
sums.set(i, tempSum);

Which would first get the sum from sums, then add counterEntrys value to it, and then replace the value you already have in sums with the new sum.